# how to map the multiple different domain into single wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am having differnt domain like test.com,wiki.com,slash.com . How can  map all the domain into single wordpress installation . I am tried with wordpress mu domain mapping. But its gets the subdomain of the main domain . Kindly suggest any solution?

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to use multiple domains, one for each sub site, you need to use [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) plugin and follow these steps described in [OttoPress](http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-multisite-domain-mapping-tutorial/) complete documentation on this topic..

Except if you are hosted on [GoDaddy](http://www.godaddy.com/) follow steps described in [G. Michael Guy](http://gmichaelguy.com/blog/2010/11/28/my-wordpress-3-0-multi-site-domain-mapping-with-godaddy/)'s tutorial. It can't post it here because of long steps.